# ExecutorService unchecked assignment

Tags: java, multithreading, generics, executorservice

I'm learning about ExecutorService and Callables, but get a warning from intelij saying I'm doing an unchecked assignment for this line:

```
Future<OrderWorker<OfferType>> future = executorService.submit(new OrderWorker<OfferType>(anOfferSet));
```

I don't get how to assign correctly. Here's the code:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<Future<OrderWorker<OfferType>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (OfferType anOfferSet : offerSet) {
    // the next assignment is unchecked:
    Future<OrderWorker<OfferType>> future = executorService.submit(new OrderWorker<OfferType>(anOfferSet));
    futures.add(future);
}
```

---

Order Worker:

```
public class OrderWorker<I extends OfferType> implements DataWorker {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OrderWorker.class);
    private final OfferType offer;

    public OrderWorker(I data) {
        this.offer = data;
    }

    public OfferType getOffer() {
        return offer;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        log.info(offer.getListingPrice().getAmount());
        return this;
    }
}
```

DataWorker interface:

```
interface DataWorker<I extends OfferType> extends Callable<I> {}
```

`OfferType` is a simple POJO class.

EDIT

I also tried to give DataWorker a type when implementing it:

```
public class OrderWorker<I extends OfferType> implements DataWorker<I>
```

This gives an error saying call() in OrderWorker clashes with call() in Callable -> incompatible return type

What am I doing wrong, and what do I have to do to make the assignment checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to change is the declaration of `OrderWorker` and the return type of `call`, as next:

```
public class OrderWorker<I extends OfferType> implements Callable<OrderWorker<I>> {
    ...
    @Override
    public OrderWorker<I> call() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the interface for other purposes, but when extending Callable in the interface like `extends Callable<OrderWorker<I>>` it works as you've described! Thank you!